# Java Layout difference on identical screen resolutions

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, screen-resolution

I have two screens that are using the same resolution (1280x1024), but one of them has a refresh rate of 59.9 HZ, and the other one has a refresh rate of 75 HZ. I have a full software that's developed using Java (and running under OpenSuse 10.0). The problem is that the Jtables in this software are being displayed differently on both screens: They're being displayed perfectly on one screen, and on the other screen, the widths of the columns are increasing, which is hiding some of the columns.
The other difference that I was able to get from both screens, is when I used the Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution(), which gave me 93 on the "good display" screen and 95 on the "bad display" screen.

My question is, why would two screens that are using the same resolution, display GUI components differently? Does it have to do anything with the refresh rate or with the DPI of the screen?

Comment: Maybe post a screen shot of the application on each screen?

Comment: Are they on the same video card?

Comment: Yes, both of them are using Intel Corporation 945G Integrated Graphics Controller

Comment: Normally the refresh rate has no impact similar to what you describe. However, DPI resolution ca definitely have such an impact. But it depends a lot on other points such as: do you hard-code sizes (in pixels) in your application? Do you define different font sizes for both screens (at OS/Window Manager level)? It could help if you could provide a code snippet that produces that problem on your screens, in addition to screenshots, as asked in the first comment.

Comment: I sorry, just my view, this discousion going wrong direction @Mouhammed Soueidane please what and how number of GPU cores and Monitors returs http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html example about http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Graphic-Environment.htm

Comment: Post some drawcode and screenshots, that would help more

Comment: Couple of ideas to look at: If display 2 is logically to the right of screen 1, both will have positive values for x & y. If display 2 is logically to the left of display 1,  display 2 will use negative values for x. There could be a math error related to the negative x. Second, Try changing the FRACTIONALMETRICS rendering hint on Graphics2D and see if that changes the behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your available fonts. The logical font names (serif, sansserif, monospaced, dialog, dialoginput) are created from the fonts available on your machine.

Per the [Font javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html):

> Typically, each logical font name maps to several physical fonts in order to cover a large range of characters.

So, if the available fonts do not match, Java may be substituting different physical font characters. That can cause the behavior you are describing.

Comment: in due all respect to your person, that's nothing to do with multiplayed monitors on multicores GPU :-)

Comment: Ah, I did not realize this was a single system. I thought though this was a difference between 2 systems. My apologies.